# python module for CGH analysis

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am searching for module in python for CGH analysis for bioinformatics. I find some tools but they are web based and I didnt find any module in python which deals with CGH analysis also with all graphs.
I want command line module in python.

Kindly let me know If anyone knows about the same.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you will find one. If you're doing array work and you want to drive it via the command line, learn some R and pick up one of the many packages for CGH analysis.  I'm sure there are some python/R bindings out there to help you.

http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/html/CGHcall.html

http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.11/bioc/html/CGHnormaliter.html

http://www.hindawi.com/journals/cfg/2009/201325/

Comment: but i am wondering how it is possible that language like python do not have modules in the field of CGH?

Comment: Because they're not specialist statistical languages. Perl doesn't have them either.  The simple fact of the matter is that R is much more appropriate and much better supported for this type of work.  Use the right tool for the right job :)